# How to get all possible Regex Matches

Tags: c#, regex

Based off a regex string I would like to get a list of all the possible strings that would match the regex.

Example:
Given a regex string like...
`^(en/|)resources/case(-| )studies/`

I want to get a list of all the possible strings that would match the regex expression. Like...

`^en/resources/case-studies/`

or
`^/resources/case-studies/`

or
`^en/resources/case studies/`

or
`^/resources/case studies/`

Thank you

Comment: This is not possible in general. For example, a regex of the form `.` would have to spit out all possible Unicode characters -- and that's *one* character. Algorithms can be written that work a little more high level, but writing those is definitely outside the scope of one answer. There is, in any case, no built-in functionality in the framework for this. (Also, `^` does not actually match any character; it anchors the regex to the beginning of the line.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in regex `^` denotes the beginning of the line. You must escape it

Try

```
\^(en)?/resources/case(-|\s)studies/
```

explanation:

`\^` is `^` escaped.

`(en)?` is optionally `en`, where `?` means zero or one times.

`/resources/case` the text as is.

`(-|\s)` minus sign or white space.

`studies/` the text as is.

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PO4wKV